# Why MPMoviePlayerController is showing a black view?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to run a direct video from youtube. JA managed with local video but want to run it directly from youtube.
I made the alterations in my code but now only a black screen appears.

this is my code:

```
- (void)playVideo {
   // NSString *videoFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.youtube.com/embed/FuiVknDC7dM"];
    //self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoFile]];
    self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];

    [self.moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
    //self.moviePlayer.fullscreen = YES;
    self.moviePlayer.allowsAirPlay = YES;
    [self.moviePlayer play];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That youtube link isn't actually a direct link to the video file - MPMoviePlayerController will not be able to play it.

You need to use a UIWebView, which will load the web content, and when the user clicks the video it will launch in a MPMoviePlayerController as you expect.